# How to get data on OkHttp response code 304?

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I read that a response with code 304 (Not Modified) should have no body. In that case, does OkHttp get the body from the cache, or shall we get it explicitely, i.e.

```
if reponseCode == 304:
      body = <getDataFromCache>
```

In the latter case, how to get the data from the cache?

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

File cacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "responses");

Cache cache = null;
try {
    cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10M
    client.setCache(cache);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("AbstractFeedIntentService", "Could not create http cache", e);
}

Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
requestBuilder.url(url);
Request request = requestBuilder.build();

Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();

// if code==304, does the response contain the data from the cache. If not, how to get it?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OkHttp` will return data from its response cache.

Comment: Thanks. Is that documented anywhere?